# Which one to use : pas le seul or pas seul ?

Tags: grammaire

I'm a beginner French student and just got into this problem after reading the sentence below, which format should I use ? I read something that said:

> Dites-lui qu'il n'est pas **le** seul

But what I thought it should be like:

> Dites-lui qu'il n'est pas seul *(without **le**)*

If the first sentence is true why *le* is used?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Dites-lui qu'il n'est pas **le seul**."* means:

> Tell him he's not **the only one**.

But on the other side, *"Dites-lui qu'il n'est pas **seul**."* means:

> Tell him he is not **alone**.